# Large excel file not saved correctly

Tags: c#, excel

I hope this is the right place to ask my question.

In my C# application I need to save data to an Excel file (I am using OfficeOpenXml) with a user selected sampling period varying between 30 seconds and 1 hour.

The Excel file is created at startup, then when new data arrives I open the file for writing, append the new measurements and then close the file again.

If the user selected period is 30 seconds, in case of "long" recordings (> 12 hours) the Excel file disappears when I stop the program. No problems instead in case of shorter recordings.

Have any of you experienced similar problems? Thoughts? Solutions?
Any help is very welcome.

Comment: How about auto-saving it after a certain amount of time?

Comment: I cannot do that. Since this application should log some process measures it is important that they are saved as soon as they arrive, keeping them in memory is risky: in case of power loss, or anything that would cause the app to close the measures would just be lost.

Comment: Consider creating a copy of the file in system temp directory, add data and overwrite existing excel file.